# Manipulate CSV files

Tags: python, python-3.x

Create a solution that accepts an input identifying the name of a CSV file, for example, "input1.csv". Each file contains two rows of comma-separated values. Import the built-in module csv and use its open() function and reader() method to create a dictionary of key:value pairs for each row of comma-separated values in the specified file. Output the file contents as two dictionaries.

The solution output should be in the format

```
{'key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}
{'key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'key': 'value'}
```

I tried this but this prints in string format. The output needs to be a dictionary with quotations around key value pair.

```
import csv

# file_name = input()

dict_1 = {}
dict_2 = {}


file = open('input1.csv', 'r')

content = csv.reader(file)

create_list = []

for line in content:
    create_list.append(line)

file.close()

# Create the dictionary from the _list for the first row...
for i in range(0, len(create_list[0]), 2):
    dict_1[create_list[0][i]] = create_list[0][i + 1]

# Create the dictionary from the _list for the second row...
for i in create_list:
    dict_2[create_list[1][i]] = create_list[1][i + 1]

# Print the first dictionary as per the required format...
print("{", end="")
for key, val in dict_1.items():
    if val != create_list[0][-1]:
        print("{}:{}".format(key, val), end=',')
    else:
        print("{}:{}".format(key, val), end='}')

# Print the second dictionary as per the required format...
print("\n{", end="")
for key, val in dict_2.items():
    if val != create_list[1][-1]:
        print("{}:{}".format(key, val), end=',')
    else:
        print("{}:{}".format(key, val), end='}')
```

Comment: You don't have quotes in `print("{}:{}".format(key, val), end=',')` so you can add them `print("'{}':'{}'".format(key, val), end=',')`. Then again, have you tried `print(dict_1)`?

Comment: you should actually use double quotes for this, as it then becomes a valid NDJSON

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use the JSON standard library to easily turn dict objects into strings, and do some string replacement to turn the double quotes that JSON uses into single quotes.

```py
import csv
import json

with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    with open("somefile.csv") as infile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
        for d in reader:
            outfile.write(json.dumps(d).replace('"', "'") + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
    filename = input()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    line = csv.reader(f)
    for l in line:
        temp_list = [x.replace(' ', '') for x in l]
        dictionary = zip(temp_list[::2], temp_list[1::2])
        print(dict(dictionary))
```

> This is how I solved it and returned correct. I just stripped the list of whitespace and then converted the list into a dictionary.